# Create list with jijna2 regex_search - NoneType problem

Tags: regex, ansible, jinja2, nonetype

I'm facing 2 problems:

Problem 1.
I'm trying to filter a list with jinja2 `regex_search` but I alse get  `None` matches.

Problem 2.
Each elements of the new list seems to be list of one element (sigth!!!).

My code.

```yaml
- name: Regex_Search Test
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    my_list:
      - app-be-dev01-2
      - app-be-dev02-2
      - app-be-dev02-3
      - app-be-dev03-2
      - app-foo-2
      - app-be-dev04-1
      - app-be-dev04-2

  tasks:
  - name: Varsmng
    set_fact:
      customer_instances: >-
         {%       for instance in my_list  -%} {{ customer_instances | default([]) + [ instance | string | regex_search('app-be-(.*)-([0-9]*)', '\1' ) ]  }}
         {%-      endfor %}

  - name: Debug
    debug:
      msg:
       - "customer_instances:  {{ customer_instances }}"
```

My output.

```
TASK [Varsmng] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/cin0633a/progetti/ansible/testenv/test.yml:19
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "customer_instances": "[[u'dev01']][[u'dev02']][[u'dev02']][[u'dev03']][None][[u'dev04']][[u'dev04']]  "
    }, 
    "changed": false
```

As you can see, each element has a double square brackets. And can I avoid `None` values?

Answer (score 1):

You get a list for each element because `regex_search` returns a list when you use the replace feature with capture groups in the expression.

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug -e toto=bla-bli-blo -a "msg={{ toto | regex_search('(bla).*') }}"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "bla-bli-blo"
}
$ ansible localhost -m debug -e toto=bla-bli-blo -a "msg={{ toto | regex_search('(bla).*', '\\1') }}"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": [
        "bla"
    ]
}
```

And you get `None` values because some items do not match your regex.

You can get your result with a better approach IMO using specific filters rather than a complex jinja2 template. The following playbook:

```yaml
- name: Regex_Search Test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    my_list:
      - app-be-dev01-2
      - app-be-dev02-2
      - app-be-dev02-3
      - app-be-dev03-2
      - app-foo-2
      - app-be-dev04-1
      - app-be-dev04-2

    searchreg: >-
      app-be-(.*)-([0-9]*)

    my_filtered_list: >-
      {{
        my_list |
        select('regex', searchreg) |
        map('regex_replace', searchreg, '\1')
      }}

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_filtered_list
```

Gives:

```
PLAY [Regex_Search Test] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_filtered_list": [
        "dev01",
        "dev02",
        "dev02",
        "dev03",
        "dev04",
        "dev04"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

- Note1: you can pipe the `unique` filter if you want unique environment results
- Note2: if you are using ansible < 2.10, you will have to add the `list` filter at the end of all others to get the actual result.